Unable to Create Loan Records in ASP.NET Core MVC application
I'm developing an ASP.NET Core MVC application with Entity Framework Core and I'm facing an issue where Loan records are not being created in the database.
Here's a brief overview of my setup and the issue :
Model Loan has properties including
Id, BookId, MemberId, LoanDate, ReturnDate

LibraryContext has DbSet<Loan> Loans, and the relationships between Loan, Book, and Member are set up in the OnModelCreating method.
The LoanController has Create actions for both GET and POST requests. The POST action is supposed to handle form submissions to add new Loan records.
The Create view contains a form with fields for BookId, MemberId, LoanDate and ReturnDate.
Issue: the Create action method in the LoanController does not create Loan records in the database. Despite submitting the form, no new records appear in the database, and no exceptions are thrown.
Models/Loan.cs:
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LibraryManagementSystem.Models
{
    public class Loan
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        public Book Book { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        public Member Member { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime LoanDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ReturnDate { get; set; }
    }
}

LoanController:
public class LoanController : Controller
{
    private readonly LibraryContext _context;

    public LoanController(LibraryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Loan
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var loans = await _context.Loans
            .Include(l => l.Book)
            .Include(l => l.Member)
            .ToListAsync();
        return View(loans);
    }

    // GET: Loan/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var loan = await _context.Loans
            .Include(l => l.Book)
            .Include(l => l.Member)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (loan == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(loan);
    }

    // GET: Loan/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["BookId"] = new SelectList(_context.Books, "Id", "Title");
        ViewData["MemberId"] = new SelectList(_context.Members, "Id", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Loan/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,BookId,MemberId,LoanDate,ReturnDate")] Loan loan)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(loan);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["BookId"] = new SelectList(_context.Books, "Id", "Title", loan.BookId);
        ViewData["MemberId"] = new SelectList(_context.Members, "Id", "Name", loan.MemberId);
        return View(loan);
    }

    // GET: Loan/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var loan = await _context.Loans.FindAsync(id);
        if (loan == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["BookId"] = new SelectList(_context.Books, "Id", "Title", loan.BookId);
        ViewData["MemberId"] = new SelectList(_context.Members, "Id", "Name", loan.MemberId);
        return View(loan);
    }

    // POST: Loan/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,BookId,MemberId,LoanDate,ReturnDate")] Loan loan)
    {
        if (id != loan.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(loan);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!LoanExists(loan.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["BookId"] = new SelectList(_context.Books, "Id", "Title", loan.BookId);
        ViewData["MemberId"] = new SelectList(_context.Members, "Id", "Name", loan.MemberId);
        return View(loan);
    }

    // GET: Loan/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var loan = await _context.Loans
            .Include(l => l.Book)
            .Include(l => l.Member)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (loan == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(loan);
    }

    // POST: Loan/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var loan = await _context.Loans.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Loans.Remove(loan);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool LoanExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Loans.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }
}

LoanCreate.cshtml:
@page
@model LibManagementSystem.Pages.Loans.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Loan</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Loan.BookId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Loan.BookId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.BookId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Loan.MemberId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Loan.MemberId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.MemberId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Loan.LoanDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Loan.LoanDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Loan.LoanDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Loan.ReturnDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Loan.ReturnDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Loan.ReturnDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}

LoanCreate.cshtml.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using LibraryManagementSystem.Data;
using LibraryManagementSystem.Models;

namespace LibManagementSystem.Pages.Loans
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly LibraryManagementSystem.Data.LibraryContext _context;

        public CreateModel(LibraryManagementSystem.Data.LibraryContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            ViewData["BookId"] = new SelectList(_context.Books, "Id", "Id");
            ViewData["MemberId"] = new SelectList(_context.Members, "Id", "Id");
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Loan Loan { get; set; } = default!;

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.Loans.Add(Loan);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}


Have you tried to put a breakpoint in Create method to check if SaveChangesAsync is called?

why do you have both a loan controller and a loancreate code-behind? it's confusing-- can't determine where your form data is going

Your codes which shared to create the Loan mode is a razor page, not MVC controller view.
I suggest you could modify the view and create the view for that create controller method.
1.Add view for the controller create method:

2.Modify the view like below:
@model Loan

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Loan</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post" asp-action="Create" asp-asp-controller="LoanController">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BookId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="BookId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.BookId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="MemberId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="MemberId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.MemberId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LoanDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LoanDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LoanDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ReturnDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ReturnDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ReturnDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{
        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
    }
}

Result

